# Как начать отладку в PyCharm?

Tags: python, отладка, pycharm

Доброго дня всем!
никак не могу начать отладку в PyCharm( ставлю красную точку сбоку, запускаю - программа выполняется и всё, остановки не происходит. Объясните, пожалуйста, как тут дебажить(

Comment: Вероятно, нужно запускать в режиме дебага. В Qt я тоже не сразу въехал в это дело, привыкаешь же к удобствам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рядом с кнопкой старта (зеленная стрелочка), есть зеленный паук, его и нажмите для запуска в режиме дэбага

Также по умолчанию используется комбинация клавиш `Shift+F9`